# Uninstall Memcached PHP 5.4 (Installed by Brew)

Tags: php, macos, memcached, osx-mountain-lion, php-5.5

I have to confess I messed up, I installed the wrong version of Memcached for PHP on my OSX 10.8.5 machine. Basically I used

> brew install php54-memcached

After using brew `install memcached`. My apache won't start up and then I realised I have PHP5.5 ... :(

**UPDATE:** I tried to remove php 5.4 which I think brew has installed as a dependancy which is causing a conflict. I did `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/`

Restarted Apache but no cigar.

Any help would be appreciated I tried `brew rm php54-memcached` but obviously this was no help.

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
brew uninstall php54-memcached --force
```

More tips [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md).

Answer (score 0):

Ok after hours of digging I think I found it...

Basically Brew had installed 5.4 alongside but changed something in 5.5, it might even have been the self installed PHP (not brew). When I switched the module in the http.conf to point to the 5.4 installation libphp5.so it worked and then when I switched it to the apparent 5.5 version it failed again.

So I just unlinked both and cleared it via homebrew and then effectively reinstalled PHP5.5 via homebrew.

Ideally the php.ini that is used by the Brew installation is the same as the one I was using before so that was nice when I got it back up and running.

I double checked to see if I needed to remove any old files. I only needed to remove the old 5.5 version folder.

One thing to that baffles me though is that when I went into http.conf to change the PHP module link I'm pretty sure it wasn't linking to the Brew version of my PHP5.5 installation but instead to "/usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so". This would suggest I was never using the brew version... I'm so confused.

Perhaps when I installed php5.4 by accident it change the bash path... either way everything looks in shape just now so fingers crossed.

Some points to help others:

- I followed [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php) to make sure I set it up right
- I made sure to link http.conf to the Brew install libphp5.so
- I made sure my LaunchAgents plist was the right one
- I made sure to update the $PATH (no idea what that really does and welcome any explanations - I've always wondered)

I realise this is terribly formatted and a rambling, but I'm exhausted :)